# Setting Up PHP & SQLite with a "Command Script"?

Tags: php, macos, sqlite, scripting, shell

I'm trying to setup PHP & SQLite on my mac with by following this page: http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/internet/phpeasyway.html. The code posted on the site is supposed to be run in a command script but I don't know how to make that happen. I've tried making a bash script and an applescript but both of those give errors. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation has this line of code:

```
user_db=${user_www}/${filename}-db.sqlite3
```

Is the `filename` variable defined? Does the database exist in that location?

Comment: Database doesn't have to exist, sqlite tries to make it for you. But you do need to have the rights to do so. Also, try a absolute path to the database file.

Comment: Well, the database does have to exist if you're trying to run a query other than create against it.

Comment: To be honest I never fully understood what the big chunk of code in the first part of the documentation/tutorial was telling me to do. I just uncommented the httpd.conf file manually.

To answer your question there is no database on my machine yet. When I give $user_db a path in the php file I still get the same error.

Comment: Make sure the path is valid (directory exists, at least), and read the instructions carefully. It really looks like a good guide.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After reading more closely I think I don't know enough about scripting on the mac to get this thing to run.